# What is the right way of updating a fork of a Github repo, with a pending pull request to upstream?

Tags: git, github, git-flow

Lets say there is a public project A on Github, using the git-flow model. Suppose I create my own fork My/A. I commit some changes to the develop branch of My/A. I then create a pull request to merge my new changes into the develop branch of A. Meanwhile, the develop branch of A is updated, and I want the changes to A in my fork so that I can use them together with my own changes. **What is the best way of doing this?** I suppose I can execute these commands on a local copy of My/A, supposing that the remote `upstream` is pointing at A.

1. `git rebase upstream/develop`
2. `git push -f origin/develop`

But this way, I think that Github might include all new changes in A as part of my pull request, but I'm not sure.

Comment: You should create a new branch in your fork specifically for your PR, so you can keep in sync other branches until the PR is merged.

Comment: @Tensibai, I could do that but in the git-flow workflow, new features are merged into develop. What I could also do, create a branch from develop that I can keep in sync with upstream/develop while I wait.

Comment: You didn't mention git-flow at any point in your Q... Anyway, push to github your feature branch, and create the PR from this feature branch, targeting original develop branch.

Comment: @Tensibai, that's a good solution thank you. Please post it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best idea:

Create a feature branch, push it to github and create the PR from it.

Obviously this mean you'll have to merge again your feature branch each time your sync your develop branch from upstream branch.